# Как написать цикл чтоб получить первые 10 массивы из url // fetch()

Tags: javascript

```
const requestURL = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos'


function sendRequest(url) {
    return(fetch(url).then(response =>{
        return response.json()
    }))
}
sendRequest(requestURL)
.then(data => console.log(data))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const requestURL = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos'

function sendRequest(url) {
    return(fetch(url).then(response =>{
        return response.json()
    }))
}

sendRequest(requestURL)
.then(data =>
{
    data = data.slice(0, 10);

    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    {
        console.log(data[i])
    }
});

// or

sendRequest(requestURL)
.then(data =>
{
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        console.log(data[i])
    }
});
```

Comment: а как написать цикл?

Comment: Какой конкретно результат вы хотите увидеть?

Comment: пишу цикл     for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  console.log(data[i])
 }

Comment: не работает ошибка ...хочу достучаться первые 10 фотографии

Comment: Обновил ответ, так?

Comment: спасибо дорогой

Comment: а как сделать чтоб они все были в массиве ?

Comment: Так? Первый вариант как раз и делал это.